# Which Java am I using on my Windows 10 system?

Tags: java

I have installed multiple versions of Java on my Windows 10 system.
[image]

I am not sure how Java is set up.  I see the following entry under environment variables
[image]

I see the following files in the directory above

[image]

Then there are the installations in the 'Program Files' directory

[image]

I had 1.8.0_202 on my system.  Then I installed update 1.8.0_361.  The system continues to be using update 202.  What I need to do to make the system use update 361.  Disabling update 202 does not to the job. Also, if you can explain how all these different entries (the environment variables, the files in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath)  are used.

Comment: What if you were to uninstall the Java binaries from your system and then reinstall only the one you cared about?  It's been pretty much 10 years since I tried to do Java on Windows but I think the sentiment is, if you have two conflicting binaries on your system, removing them both and then replacing only the one you want would usually do the trick.

Comment: Actually, I need both systems to be used with different applications. I can uninstall one and that would work.  But I would like to keep both systems.

Comment: 1.8.0_361 and 1.8.0_202 are both the same version 1.8, just different security patch levels. You don't need both. Actually, what you have is 1.8.0_361 JRE only and 1.8.0_202 JDK and JRE. Things that need the JDK are using patch 202 because you haven't updated the JDK, you've only updated the JRE.

Comment: Java 1.8 is backwards-compatible with those point changes, so there's no real value in keeping the slightly older _202 version over the _361 version.  Otherwise...your environment is "ideal" in that it has all of the Java versions it needs...

Comment: You can open a dos or ps window and type in java -version and that will tell you which one your using.  Typically the first one to show up in your path variable is the one it will use, unless it is installed as part of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `java` at the command prompt, Windows will look for `java.exe` in the directories specified by the `PATH` environment variable, starting with the first one. In your case, that's `C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`. That folder contains a few files which are nothing more than symbolic links to executables found in the latest installed JRE. In your case, that will be `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_361\bin`.

What seems to be happening is that the JRE gets automatically updated, and you've got the latest JRE installed. But the JDK is *not* automatically updated: you have to do that manually. You still have version 1.8.0_202 of the JDK. So when you type `javac` (to compile a Java source file), you are using the JDK, and that's found in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin` which is the last directory specified in your `PATH` environment variable.

You can clean up by removing the current versions of JRE and JDK and install the latest JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any IDE?
If you are using eclipse then right-click on the project select build path then configure the build path there is an option JRE system library edit it and choose the latest java version.